# Long running INSERT query on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have been sniffing out forums and blogs lately, but need some help with a long running query. It's part of a system of stored procedures. This specified statement used to run in about 5 minutes, but lately has been running up to 72 hours!

Here's the setup:

SQL Server 2005 with 28GB memory. Two mountpoints to a SAN with shared disks consisting of 10 spindles. Data is on one mountpoint, Log on another, tempdb on data space. Just one userdatabase on this server.

Here's two tables, `condit` and `condmod`. `Condit` contains 800K records, `condmod` is initially empty. I issue a truncate mcmain.condmod before the process starts, for testing purposes.

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DF__condit__con_notm__000AF8CF]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE [mcmain].[condit] DROP CONSTRAINT [DF__condit__con_notm__000AF8CF]
END
GO

/****** Object:  Table [mcmain].[condit]    Script Date: 02/07/2012 11:57:47 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[mcmain].[condit]') AND type in (N'U'))
  DROP TABLE [mcmain].[condit]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [mcmain].[condit]    Script Date: 02/07/2012 11:57:49 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[mcmain].[condit]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [mcmain].[condit](
    [con_levgln] [char](13) NULL,
    [con_stat] [char](4) NULL,
    [con_dscgrp] [char](35) NULL,
    [con_levart] [char](20) NULL,
    [con_desc] [char](50) NULL,
    [con_disc1] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
    [con_disc2] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
    [con_disc3] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
    [con_ntprce] [numeric](9, 0) NULL,
    [con_dtstrt] [datetime] NULL,
    [con_dtend] [datetime] NULL,
    [con_volc] [char](8) NULL,
    [con_updnmr] [char](20) NULL,
    [con_notmod] [bit] NULL,
    [con_ascver] [char](5) NULL,
    [con_prddat] [datetime] NULL,
    [con_cusgln] [char](13) NULL,
    [con_cusdeb] [char](40) NULL,
    [con_rowid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DF__condit__con_notm__000AF8CF]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE [mcmain].[condit] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [con_notmod]
END    
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DF__condmod__com_not__7E22B05D]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE [mcmain].[condmod] DROP CONSTRAINT [DF__condmod__com_not__7E22B05D]
END
GO

/****** Object:  Table [mcmain].[condmod]    Script Date: 02/07/2012 11:57:56 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[mcmain].[condmod]') AND type in (N'U'))
  DROP TABLE [mcmain].[condmod]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [mcmain].[condmod]    Script Date: 02/07/2012 11:57:58 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[mcmain].[condmod]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [mcmain].[condmod](
    [com_levgln] [char](13) NULL,
    [com_stat] [char](4) NULL,
    [com_dscgrp] [char](35) NULL,
    [com_levart] [char](20) NULL,
    [com_desc] [char](50) NULL,
    [com_disc1] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
    [com_disc2] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
    [com_disc3] [numeric](5, 0) NULL,
    [com_ntprce] [numeric](9, 0) NULL,
    [com_dtstrt] [datetime] NULL,
    [com_dtend] [datetime] NULL,
    [com_volc] [char](8) NULL,
    [com_updnmr] [char](20) NULL,
    [com_notmod] [bit] NULL,
    [com_ascver] [char](8) NULL,
    [com_prddat] [datetime] NULL,
    [com_cusgln] [char](13) NULL,
    [com_cusdeb] [char](40) NULL,
    [com_rowid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DF__condmod__com_not__7E22B05D]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE [mcmain].[condmod] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [com_notmod]
END
GO
```

Here's the isolated code that runs a long time:

```
DECLARE @TempIdTable TABLE ([com_rowid] Int PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT @TempIdTable([com_rowid])
    SELECT cmd.[com_rowid]
    FROM [mcmain].[condmod] AS cmd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [mcmain].[condit] AS cdt
      ON con_levgln = com_levgln
     AND IsNull(con_dscgrp,'')  = IsNull(com_dscgrp,'')
     AND IsNull(con_levart,'')  = IsNull(com_levart,'')
     AND IsNull(con_volc,'')    = IsNull(com_volc,'')
     AND IsNull(con_cusgln,'')  = IsNull(com_cusgln,'')
     AND IsNull(con_cusdeb,'')  = IsNull(com_cusdeb,'')
    WHERE con_levgln is NULL

    --select * from @TempIdTable
INSERT INTO mcmain.condit(con_levgln
                ,con_stat
                ,con_dscgrp
                ,con_levart
                ,con_desc
                ,con_disc1
                ,con_disc2
                ,con_disc3
                ,con_ntprce
                ,con_dtstrt
                ,con_dtend
                ,con_volc
                ,con_notmod
                ,con_updnmr
                ,con_ascver
                ,con_cusgln
                ,con_cusdeb)
        SELECT  com_levgln
                ,com_stat
                ,com_dscgrp
                ,com_levart
                ,com_desc
                ,com_disc1
                ,com_disc2
                ,com_disc3
                ,com_ntprce
                ,com_dtstrt
                ,com_dtend
                ,com_volc
                ,com_notmod
                ,com_updnmr
                ,com_ascver
                ,com_cusgln
                ,com_cusdeb
        FROM [mcmain].[condmod] AS cmd
        INNER JOIN @TempIdTable AS tit
          ON tit.com_rowid = cmd.com_rowid
```

The insert into the `@TempIdTable` takes forever. What can I do to speed up this process?

TIA

Cees Cappelle

p.s. I have clustered indexes on both tables, like:

```
/****** Object:  Index [condmodTest]    Script Date: 02/07/2012 13:24:34 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[mcmain].[condmod]') AND name = N'condmodTest')
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [condmodTest] ON [mcmain].[condmod] 
(
    [com_levgln] ASC,
    [com_dscgrp] ASC,
    [com_levart] ASC,
    [com_volc] ASC,
    [com_cusgln] ASC,
    [com_cusdeb] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

If I do a straight select (just now), it takes 2 seconds.

Here's the code:

```
SELECT  com_levgln
        ,com_stat
        ,com_dscgrp
        ,com_levart
        ,com_desc
        ,com_disc1
        ,com_disc2
        ,com_disc3
        ,com_ntprce
        ,com_dtstrt
        ,com_dtend
        ,com_volc
        ,com_notmod
        ,com_updnmr
        ,com_ascver
        ,com_cusgln
        ,com_cusdeb
FROM mcmain.condmod
LEFT OUTER JOIN mcmain.condit 
    ON  con_levgln  = com_levgln
    AND IsNull(con_dscgrp,'')   = IsNull(com_dscgrp,'')
    AND IsNull(con_levart,'')   = IsNull(com_levart,'')
    AND IsNull(con_volc,'')     = IsNull(com_volc,'')
    AND IsNull(con_cusgln,'')   =   IsNull(com_cusgln,'')
    AND IsNull(con_cusdeb,'')   =   IsNull(com_cusdeb,'')
WHERE   con_levgln is NULL
```

I just did a Actial Execution plan with the following code. It took 3'16'' ???

```
truncate table mcmain.condit

CREATE TABLE #TempIdTable ([com_rowid]  Int PRIMARY KEY)
--      DECLARE @TempIdTable TABLE
--          ([com_rowid]    Int PRIMARY KEY)

        INSERT #TempIdTable
            ([com_rowid])
        SELECT cmd.[com_rowid]
        FROM [mcmain].[condmod] AS cmd
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [mcmain].[condit] AS cdt
          ON con_levgln = com_levgln
         AND IsNull(con_dscgrp,'')  = IsNull(com_dscgrp,'')
         AND IsNull(con_levart,'')  = IsNull(com_levart,'')
         AND IsNull(con_volc,'')    = IsNull(com_volc,'')
         AND IsNull(con_cusgln,'')  = IsNull(com_cusgln,'')
         AND IsNull(con_cusdeb,'')  = IsNull(com_cusdeb,'')
        WHERE con_levgln is NULL
        -- AND      com_updnmr = @plannummer

            INSERT INTO mcmain.condit
                    (con_levgln
                    ,con_stat
                    ,con_dscgrp
                    ,con_levart
                    ,con_desc
                    ,con_disc1
                    ,con_disc2
                    ,con_disc3
                    ,con_ntprce
                    ,con_dtstrt
                    ,con_dtend
                    ,con_volc
                    ,con_notmod
                    ,con_updnmr
                    ,con_ascver
                    ,con_cusgln
                    ,con_cusdeb)
            SELECT  com_levgln
                    ,com_stat
                    ,com_dscgrp
                    ,com_levart
                    ,com_desc
                    ,com_disc1
                    ,com_disc2
                    ,com_disc3
                    ,com_ntprce
                    ,com_dtstrt
                    ,com_dtend
                    ,com_volc
                    ,com_notmod
                    ,com_updnmr
                    ,com_ascver
                    ,com_cusgln
                    ,com_cusdeb
            FROM [mcmain].[condmod] AS cmd
            INNER JOIN #TempIdTable AS tit
              ON tit.com_rowid = cmd.com_rowid
```

Same statement but using a tablevariable took 1'39''

When I run the sp, the same statement takes hours and hours. Still don't get it.

Comment: Bye the way, I have clustered indexes on both tables:

Comment: How long does the `SELECT` take on its own?

Comment: If you set SET ANSI_NULLS OFF and remove the isnull is it any quicker?

Comment: Martin,
If I do a select straight with a left outer join, it takes two seconds :(

Comment: @ceescap - and if you look at the execution plan for the straight `SELECT` on its own does it have a parallel plan?

Comment: @Martin, yes it has a parallel plan, using a hash match.

Answer (score 5):

If the `SELECT` itself takes a long time

You could consider using `NOT EXISTS` rather than `OUTER JOIN ... NULL` as this is often more efficient.

Also I would get rid of the non sargable `ISNULL` comparisons.

```
SELECT cmd.[com_rowid] 
FROM   [mcmain].[condmod] AS cmd 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   [mcmain].[condit] AS cdt 
                   WHERE  con_levgln = com_levgln 
                          AND EXISTS (SELECT con_dscgrp, 
                                             con_levart, 
                                             con_volc, 
                                             con_cusgln, 
                                             con_cusdeb 
                                      INTERSECT 
                                      SELECT com_dscgrp, 
                                             com_levart, 
                                             com_volc, 
                                             com_cusgln, 
                                             com_cusdeb))
```

If the `SELECT` runs quite quickly on its own but just not when inserting to the table variable then check whether in the quick case you get a parallel plan.

Queries that insert to table variables do not get parallelised so if that is the issue you could consider changing to a `#temp` table.

If neither of these suggestions help then I suggest you start monitoring the wait types when this procedure runs. See the paper ["SQL Server 2005 Waits and Queues"](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/7/a/47a548b9-249e-484c-abd7-29f31282b04d/Performance_Tuning_Waits_Queues.doc)

Comment: @ceescap - What you ran the same code inserting into a table variable and that took 7 seconds?

Comment: How have you identified that particular statement as being the problem one? The `INSERT INTO mcmain.condit` might also benefit from using a `#TEMP` table instead of a `@table_var` as it can use statistics on it. Execution plans for queries that join onto table variables can sometimes be catastrophically bad due to the one row assumption.

Comment: Martin, I interspersed my code with statements writint to a translog table, including date and time. That way I know which statement starts when and how long it takes to run from within the sp.

Comment: Testing suggests that the @Temp is faster than the #temp table.

Comment: @ceescap - You need to identify whether it is slow because you are getting a bad plan or because it is blocked waiting on something.

Comment: Strange, the @temp part actual plan shows no inserts into indexes of the condit table, while the #temp does show the index inserts. Both have the same number of rows inserted. Could the query plan of the sp be corrupted?

Comment: @ceescap - No sounds like for the `#temp` table one you are getting a "wide" plan and for the `@table_var` one you aren't because of the one row assumption. In a wide plan the index maintenance is carried out as a separate step for each index to allow sequential IO. In a narrow one all indexes are updated on a row by row basis.

Comment: I've just started the SP with the actual Execution Plan, to see if I can learn something from that.

Comment: @ceescap I suggest polling `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` while it is running to see what waits it gets.

Comment: Well you need to put in some monitoring of waitstats and execution plans to see what happens when it is slow then.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:  the use of @tables uses tempdb.**

You should try increasing the number of temp db files... you can start with the number of tempdb files equal to the number of procs you have... but as a good starting point just jump to 10... The problem you could be having is contention for tempdb files.  You should look for page latching in tempdb.

This article discusses how the generalization I wrote above is a misconception (but not necessarily wrong) but in doing so does a good job of explaining the issue.  It also points you to other articles which give informatoin on how to look for page latching.

[A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (12/30) tempdb should always have one data file per processor core](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-%281230%29-tempdb-should-always-have-one-data-file-per-processor-core.aspx)

Comment: That would only apply if the OP was creating lots of different objects in `tempdb`. Doing this can do more harm than good in a system not experiencing allocation contention.

Comment: I have a tempdb file for each processor core, i.e. 16 tempdb files.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think you are assuming this is the ONLY thing going on in the DB at the time.  Other folks could be using table variables at the same time.  Either way the theory doesn't matter.  Look at the empirical evidence. ceescap you should look to see if you have file contention.  If you don't then this isn't the problem.  If you do then... well you will know were to focus to improve performace.  Fix the file contention or stop using table variables to avoid the problem all together.  -GL

Comment: I didn't assume anything. My comment doesn't say anywhere that this **can't** apply. Agree on the empirical evidence though. Identifying whether it is a plan issue or a wait issue (and if so what wait) is the way forward.

Comment: Also out of curiosity please explain the harm that can be done?

Comment: jsobo this is the only user on the only database on this server. I don't see any file contention. I'm using this preproduction server as a testserver until this issue is solved, after which the server will be used for production services. Besides, from the tests above the @table variable outperforms the #temp table.

Comment: Because the files get used on a round robin basis it means that instead of having one stream of sequential IO you get n streams of IO to different parts of the disc. Obviously depends on `tempdb` file placement and the IO sub system how much of an issue this is,

Comment: The disk subsystem is a 100 spindle multi-node SAN on raid 1+0

Comment: I've rebuild indexes and statistics and now seem to have a 'normal' operation again. To be continued .....

Comment: You may want to look at "with recompile" on your stored proc.  The overhead might be worth it if your data that monster proc executes against changes frequently.